# UIImageView grows after image is set

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm setting a cell with constraints including and image view and loading/setting an imageview on cellForRow.

When the screen first show, it's great, but after scrolling the cell grows to fit the UIimage view despite my constraints. .it will have one of my labels grow to accommodate the larger image.. I've played with hugging/compression but something always gives except the imageview...

here it just just loaded, vs after scrolling. The image is set to aspectFill, which is what I want.. And it all looks great until it leaves the screen and comes back...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding a aspect ratio constraint fixes this, but ideally I'd like the height to be set to the CCC label's bottom, so if the labels grow, the imageView will grow.

Comment: Ahh, removing the heigh constraint fixes the issue.. It gives an error so I added one and had it remove it at build time